# como puedo descartar un commit anterior al ultimo commit en git?

Tags: git, git-commit

tengo poco tiempo trabajando con git pero aun me cuesta entender algunas cosas, siempre me surgen dudas cuando estoy trabajando con git.

Entiendo que cuándo uno hace un commit esto es para "registrar" uno o varios cambios en local y hasta que no se haga un push estos no serán visibles en el repositorio remoto.

Ok... actualmente tengo un inconveniente, estaba trabajando en algo y luego quise cambiarme a otra rama para ver como había trabajado un compañero en un archivo, para poder cambiarme de rama tuve que hacer un commit antes, lo hice y luego me cambie de rama. Posteriormente volví a mi rama y lo que habia hecho anteriormente ya no se necesitaba, así que simplemente comencé a trabajar en otra tarea que necesitaba. Ahora tengo la siguiente duda: cuándo termine esta nueva tarea y haga un push obviamente se subiran los cambios del commit que hice antes de cambiarme de rama y los del nuevo commit de la tarea en la que estoy trabajando, correcto? como haría para solo subir los cambios de mi ultimo commit y los del anterior commit descartarlos? estoy bastante enredado. Si alguien pudiera aclararme un poco el panorama se lo agradecería, he vista varias guía para entender el flujo de git pero siempre me complico cuándo estoy trabajando con el. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Para descartar los cambios del último conmigo debes dar la siguiente instrucción:

```
  git reset HEAD~1
```

Puedes añadir '--soft' o '--hard' si quieres eliminar los archivos del todo o no del Index de git.

Sí lo que necesitas es mantener una versión anterior en lugar de 'reset' la instrucción debe ser 'revert', lo que creará un 'commit' con una versión anterior del repositorio:

```
   git revert HEAD~1
```

Sí necesitas que en lugar del último sean varios anteriores puedes cambiar '~1' el número de commits a borrar o eliminar, por ejemplo '~3'.

A continuación dejo un enlace a un página con documentación que puede resultarte de ayuda con tu problema: https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/git-undo-commit/amp/

Comment: Existe algun comando para listar los commits que he hecho y que no subido al repositorio remoto?

Comment: logré ver los commit que no he subido con git log origin/rama..HEAD pero habría alguna forma de ver los archivos que contenían esos commits ?

Comment: Para ver los archivos con los que aún no se ha hecho commit es comando es 'git status', te dirá que te falta por añadir al commit, y para ver qué contenían los commit y cuando y como se han hecho 'git-log'.

Answer (score -1):

Con este comando puedes regresar a cualquier commit, solo requieres el sha de tu commit que puedes obtener con el comando git log

git checkout -b {new_branch_name} {sha1}

ej.

git checkout -b miComitdeRegreso 10a7f47fa709a2a4102432365b3ceff48558a354

Comment: ¿Qué es `sha1`? Un ejemplo completo sería lo mínimo a incluir.

Comment: Candid Moe Para obtener el sha de tu commit puedes utilizar git log.

Answer (score -1):

```
`git HEAD` y el número que quiere cambiar de commit
```

El número SHA del commit se obtiene de usar el comando `git log`.

Comment: ¿Como obtengo el número del commit? Estaría bien un ejemplo mostrando un ejemplo de la situación, los comandos involucrados y las precauciones del caso.

Comment: usa git log, este comando te permite mirar los cambios y commits que has hecho en una rama,. Además, está el número del commit que se hizo.

Comment: Tu respuesta debe enfocarse al OP en primer lugar, y a otros que vendrán después con el mismo problema. Este es el momento oportuno para guiarlo paso a paso en la solución, explicarle que es cada cosa, como funciona, en resumen, de educarlo. Una línea no es una respuesta; apenas da para un comentario. Puedes editar tu respuesta y dar todas esas explicaciones que faltaron.